# Superscrollorama animations after unPin

Tags: javascript, vertical-scrolling, gsap

I'm having a little difficulty with the Superscrollorama plugin when I pin a section of my site, and after the animations running while it's pinned, I want to animate certain elements until the next pinned content comes into place ...

Say I have this section elements ..

```
        <div id="prod_list">
        <div class="seccion amar prod1">
            <div class="prod_list_wrapper">
                <div class="elem1">1</div>
                <div class="botella"><img src="img/bott_fnd_granreserva.png" alt="Gran Juvé y Camps"></div>
                <div class="elem2">2</div>
                <div class="elem3">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="seccion rojo prod2">
            <div class="prod_list_wrapper">
                <div class="elem1">1</div>
                <div class="botella"><img src="img/bott_fnd_blancdenoirs.png" alt="Blanc de Noirs"></div>
                <div class="elem2">2</div>
                <div class="elem3">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="seccion amar prod3">
            <div class="prod_list_wrapper">
                <div class="elem1">1</div>
                <div class="botella"><img src="img/bott_fnd_milesime.png" alt="Milesime"></div>
                <div class="elem2">2</div>
                <div class="elem3">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you see, each 'seccion' has the same elements, all around a bottle. 
My JS code would pin a section, move the .elem# divs around, then unpin and let the next section take place .. and between the onUnpin and the onPin, i'd like the elements to do a little scrolled animation to fade off upwards ..

```
        var controller = $.superscrollorama();
        var pinDur = 1500;

        controller.pin( $('.prod1'), pinDur, {
            anim: (new TimelineLite())
                .append([
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod1 .elem1'), 1, 
                        {css:{top: 750, left:-100, opacity:0}, immediateRender:true}, 
                        {css:{top: 550, left:-100, opacity:1}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod1 .botella'), 1, 
                        {css:{top: 300, left:30, opacity:1}, immediateRender:true}, 
                        {css:{top: 0, left:30, opacity:1}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod1 .elem2'), 1, 
                        {css:{top: 250, left:100, opacity:0}, immediateRender:true}, 
                        {css:{top: 200, left:100, opacity:1}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod1 .elem3'), 1, 
                        {css:{top: 650, left:400, opacity:0}, immediateRender:true}, 
                        {css:{top: 500, left:400, opacity:1}, ease:Quad.easeOut})
                ]),
            onPin: function() { console.log('Pin prod1'); },
            onUnpin: function() {  console.log('unPin prod1'); }
            });

        controller.addTween( $('.prod1'),
            (new TimelineLite())
                .append([
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod1 .elem1'), .25, 
                        {css:{top:550}},
                        {css:{top:350, opacity:0}, ease:Quad.easeOut, onUpdate:function(){
                            console.log("!! " + $('.prod1 .elem1').css('top'));
                        }
                    }),
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod1 .elem2'), .25,
                        {css:{top:200}},
                        {css:{top:100}, ease:Quad.easeOut}
                        ),
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod1 .elem3'), .25,
                        {css:{top:500}},
                        {css:{top:400}, ease:Quad.easeOut}
                        )

                ]), 500, 0 );

        controller.pin( $('.prod2'), pinDur, {
            anim: (new TimelineLite())
                .append([
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod2 .elem1'), 1, 
                        {css:{top: 750, left:-100, opacity:0}, immediateRender:true}, 
                        {css:{top: 550, left:-100, opacity:1}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod2 .botella'), 1, 
                        {css:{top: 300, left:30, opacity:1}, immediateRender:true}, 
                        {css:{top: 0, left:30, opacity:1}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod2 .elem2'), 1, 
                        {css:{top: 250, left:100, opacity:0}, immediateRender:true}, 
                        {css:{top: 200, left:100, opacity:1}, ease:Quad.easeOut}),
                    TweenMax.fromTo( $('.prod2 .elem3'), 1, 
                        {css:{top: 650, left:400, opacity:0}, immediateRender:true}, 
                        {css:{top: 500, left:400, opacity:1}, ease:Quad.easeOut})
                ]),
            onPin: function() { console.log('Pin prod2'); },
            onUnpin: function() {  console.log('unPin prod2'); }
            });
```

But I can't make this addTween animation to trigger exactly when the onUnpin function goes off, AND make it sensible to the scrolling (I can fire animations from the onUnpin function, ofc, but thats not the desired behaviour)

What am I missing? Is there a way to push this animations into the stack in between the pins?

Thanks in advance!